# Postfix illegal address syntax

Tags: postfix, configuration

My postfix install is set up to forward all email going to `example.com` to my other mail server at `mail.example.net`. This works fine for all addresses except `!@example.com` -- the `example.com` server spits out `Illegal address syntax from` in the logs and`501 5.1.3 Bad recipient address syntax` to the client,

How can I tell postfix to forward `!@example.com` as well? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part) says that `!` is valid for the local part.

My configuration is as follows:

### main.cf

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mail.example.com, localhost
relay_domains = example.com
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 10.10.10.10/32
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks
smtp_tls_fingerprint_digest = sha1
smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

### /etc/aliases

```
mailer-daemon: postmaster
postmaster: root
nobody: root
hostmaster: root
usenet: root
news: root
webmaster: root
www: root
ftp: root
abuse: root
noc: root
security: root
```

### mime_header_checks

```
/^Received: (from|by) mail\.example\.net/ IGNORE
/^Message-ID:\s+<(.*?)@mail.example.net>/ REPLACE Message-ID: <$1@mail.example.com>
```

### tls_policy

```
mail.example.net fingerprint
   match=00:01:02:03:04:05:06:07:08:09:10:11:12:13:14:15:16:17:18:19:20
```

### transport

```
example.com smtp:mail.example.net
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Stylistic reasons, it fit in well with the domain name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Big Warning

Generally including special character like `!` or `%` in the local part of an address is usually a bad idea. Exclamation mark a.k.a ! is a site separator in ancient [UUCP addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc976). For the safety, you should limit local part of email address to common characters such as `[A-Z][a-z][0-9]-.+`. It will preserve compatibility across other mailserver in this planet.

---

However if you insist to use the bang `!` to alias, then you may change this parameter value in `main.cf`

```
swap_bangpath = no
```

References: [here](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/Can-t-send-to-email-starting-with-exclamation-point-td36679.html) and [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.mail.postfix.user/230706)

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted your answer but unfortunately I'm unable to vote it up (low reputation)